# UHD Drivers installation failure

Tags: usrp, uhd

I am somewhat new to posting so please forgive and correct any mistakes I make in this post (and if I lack any necessary information please tell me)

I am following Ch.6 of this guide here https://pysdr.org/content/usrp.html, and am attempting to install the UHD drivers with these following steps

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake libboost-all-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev python3-docutils python3-mako python3-numpy python3-requests python3-ruamel.yaml python3-setuptools build-essential
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd.git
cd uhd/host
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_C_API=OFF -DENABLE_MANUAL=OFF ..
make -j8
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

However, when I run the test code to ensure that I installed it correctly,

```
python3
import uhd
usrp = uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP()
samples = usrp.recv_num_samps(10000, 100e6, 1e6, [0], 50)
print(samples[0:10])
```

I get the following output.

```
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>   File <stdin>, line 1, in <module>
>> AttributeError: module 'uhd' has no attribute usrp`
```

I am unsure as to why I get this output. I had looked up this error and found this https://www.mail-archive.com/usrp-users@lists.ettus.com/msg11331.html where the person had the exact same error, and the recommendation was to alter the PYTHONPATH variable, but was unsure how to do so.

I'm running a virtual machine with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 5GB of Ram and 3 dedicated CPUs.

```
     >> -- # UHD enabled components
>> -- ######################################################
>> --   * LibUHD
>> --   * LibUHD - C API
>> --   * LibUHD - Python API
>> --   * Examples
>> --   * Utils
>> --   * Tests
>> --   * USB
>> --   * B100
>> --   * B200
>> --   * USRP1
>> --   * USRP2
>> --   * X300
>> --   * MPMD
>> --   * N300
>> --   * N320
>> --   * E320
>> --   * E300
>> --   * OctoClock
>> --   * DPDK
>> --   * SIM
```

I also attempted pybombs installation "pybombs install uhd" and still got the same error output.

If anybody knows the issue/a solution please tell me!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should install a binary, instead of from source? You can get the latest Ubuntu installers here: https://launchpad.net/~ettusresearch/+archive/ubuntu/uhd

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the UHD driver by following https://pysdr.org/content/usrp.html. While installing, I did not get any error, but while testing, I was getting the same error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File <stdin>, line 1, in <module>
>
> AttributeError: module 'uhd' has no attribute usrp

**Solution:** I resolved the error just by exporting the python3 path

`export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"`